# Responsive unordered List

Tags: html, css

I'm using the code below to display a list of features:

```
<?php

    $values = get_field('features'); 
    if($values)
    {
        echo '<ul class="fa-ul product-features">';

        foreach($values as $value)
        {
            echo '<li><i class="fa-li fa  fa-check"></i>' . $value["feature_list"] . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    ?>
```

I have a bunch of different lists with different amount of feature items. Some have 7 li points other have over 10. Basically I'm using the CSS below to when a 6th bullet is introudced it starts a new column.

```
.product-features  {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 6em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;

  li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 1.2em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }  
}
```

How do I make this mobile friendly. As of right now if there are 3 rows it will stay 3 rows even on col-sm size. How do I make it so that on col-sm no matter how many colums there are, it becomes one column on small screen size.

Comment: Media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries will do it for you, see fiddle and adjust it as needed to fit what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/28/

```
@media (max-width: 640px){
  .product-features  {
  display: inline;
  }  
}
```